# Subsonic 3.0 How to retrieve all users that belong to specific group in a many to many relationship

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, many-to-many

Lets say I have a many-to-many relationship:

- Group table
- User table
- group_user table which is a many to many table

Given the group name I would like to find all the users that belong to this group.
How can I do this with subsonic 3.0?

```
IQueryable<group_user> groupUser= group_user.All();
```

Is it possible from groupUser to get all users who belong to a specific group say group 1?
Is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

Use a linq statment.

something like (very rough):

```
var users = from gu in group_user.All()
join g on group.All()
join u on user.All()
where g.Name = "My Group"
select u;
```

If you provide me with your schema I'll be able to knockup a working example.